# Add date stamp to file name in Windows

Tags: windows-explorer, filenames

Is there a way to add a date stamp to a file name when saving/renaming it via the Windows dialog box (Windows Explorer, etc.) - either as a shortcut key or a variable. There are many files that I save with date stamps and it's becoming really annoying having to type in the YYYYMMDD each time.

Comment: This should be possible with relatively simple PowerShell script.

Answer (score 2):

Not natively to Windows, you'll need an add-on program of some kind.

One way would be to use [AutoHotKey](http://autohotkey.com) (or alike) to create a macro that will type in the date for you (in your [desired format](http://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/FormatTime.htm)).

Example AHK script:

```
^#D::
FormatTime, CurrentDateTime,, yyyyMMdd
SendInput %CurrentDateTime%
return
```

This will type the date in (i.e. for today: 20151109) whenever you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>